# Checkbox that can display a checkmark or an X

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

Trying to make a checkbox that with one click it displays a check and with two clicks it will display an "x".

is this possible? I've been looking for a way but the only thing I can find is a drop-down list that will have either or.

Answer (score 1):

That is unfortunately not possible. Best you can have is a fake custom checkbox, meaning - it will look like exactly how you wish but it won't be clickable (but it could be managed by formula or manual input). For example:

```
=IF(E23=1; IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReYTt.png");
           IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmYD6.png"))
```

[image]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Maybe one day it will be.

Comment: @user224005 you are welcome and free to not accept the answer if it helped you